# ¿Cómo ejecutar un archivo con extensión .py?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Estoy comenzando a programar en Python y sinceramente no sé casi nada.

Por el momento no sé cómo puedo ejecutar un archivo con extensión `.py` desde la terminal en ubuntu.
Sé que debo ocupar un comando en específico pero no sé cual es.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: lo habitual es `python archivo.py`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Primera manera que se me ocurre:

Suponiendo que tu archivo está localizado en `/ruta/de/archivo.py`. Utiliza:

```
python /ruta/de/archivo.py
```

#### Segunda manera.

Pon al inicio de tu archivo el *shebang* (cadena de texto que le indica a la shell con que programa ejecutar el archivo) `#!/usr/bin/env python`, es decir, en tu archivo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
...
tu código de python
```

Después dale permisos de ejecución:

```
chmod +x /ruta/de/archivo.py
```

Después ejecútalo simplemente poniendo la ruta entera `/ruta/de/archivo.py` o entra a la carpeta donde está (con puro `cd carpeta`) y cuando estés ahí ejecuta `./tu_archivo.py`. Y ya no tienes que especificar el programa que lo correrá en la terminal, como `python /ruta/de/archivo.py`, porque esa información ya vendría incluida en la primera línea del código.

De todas maneras sería bueno que revisaras algún tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes ejecutar en la terminal de Ubuntu es python3 nombrearchivo.py